# Vector of functions

Tags: python, function, loops, vector, append

I want to create a function that is modified with a loop and then I can call those different functions from a function vector.
The function to be modified would be the Am function.

The problem is that it only uses the last value of the loop, `i=1`.
So I have two equal functions, with `i=1`.
What I want is to have an Am function with `i=0`, and another with `i=1`.
Then you can call them from the vector `Afunctions`

```
Afunctions = []
 
def Am(x):
        if((x>xn[i])and(x<=xn[i+1])):
            return (x-xn[i])/h1
        elif((x>xn[i+1])and(x<xn[i+2])):
            return (1-(x-xn[i+1])/h1)
        else:
            return 0
 
for i in range(0,2,1):
    Afunctions.append(Am)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a big assumption about your intent, namely, that you want `Afunctions` to be a list of callables associated with `Am` where the value of `i` is the same as callable index in `Afunctions`.  If that is a correct assumption than the following code should work:

```
from functools import partial

Afunctions = []
 
def Am(x, i):
        if((x>xn[i])and(x<=xn[i+1])):
            return (x-xn[i])/h1
        elif((x>xn[i+1])and(x<xn[i+2])):
            return (1-(x-xn[i+1])/h1)
        else:
            return 0
 
for i in range(0,2,1):
    Afunctions.append(partial(Am, i=i)) 

Afunctions
```

Output

```
[functools.partial(<function Am at 0x000001D1F6157920>, i=0),
 functools.partial(<function Am at 0x000001D1F6157920>, i=1)]
```